# Windows Phone 7 Access Sms inbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, sms, inbox

Is it possible to access and read all the inbox messages of user? It is possible in android.I searched it for WP7 but did not get any useful info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible for security considerations